# how to get notification when someone request to join a google meets I setup when I am not in that meets yet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, notifications, google-workspace, google-meet

1. setup a meets but not joined it yet.
2. share the meets link to joe.
3. joe click the link and request for approve to join the meets.
4. can I get a notification that joe is asking for join into the meets.

maybe it will need some GAS programming?

Comment: There currently is no API to do this. Are you a G Suite Admin?  What have you tried with Apps Script?

Comment: I am a G Suite admin, but sorry I haven't tried anything using Apps Script yet.

Comment: Have you written any code or done research with possible APIs?

Comment: yes, I do did some research. And sadly found that google do not provide any meets API yet.

Comment: I did a quick search in Google's Issue Tracker and found this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/123896461 which might be of interest to you. Click on the `٭` icon to indicate you are affected. If it is not quite what you would like as a feature, then you could create a new one and post it here too for reference.

Comment: thank you! voted +1 in second. Google do the job! >_<